# Apache rewrite for simple HTML site internationalization

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I made a simple HTML site (single index.html page) with two buttons to switch between languages (IT<->EN). Italian index.html is in `it` subfolder, english index.html is in `en` subfolder. The buttons modify the URL by replacing `/en/` with `/it/` and viceversa, allowing to switch between the pages. Everything works fine in locale. Good.

On the server, I have this folder tree

```
root (www.mysite.com)
  .htaccess (rules for rewriting)
  public_html
    index.html (a blank page)
    it
      index.html
    en
      index.html
```

Accessing www.mysite.com I get the blank index, as expected. Adding `RewriteEngine On` on the .htaccess and accessing www.mysite.com/public_html/it/index.html, I access the italian index and the language switch button works fine (in /en/index.html it works, too). Fine.

What I want is that:

1. www.mysite.com goes to italian index automatically, without displaying the complete url (www.mysite.com/public_html/it/index.html) but just the root (www.mysite.com) or at least the url without "public_html" (www.mysite.com/it/index.html)
2. the  language switching buttons must work

I managed to get point 1, so I go to italian index with URL that is just www.mysite.com, by adding this to .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule public_html/index.html public_html/it/index.html
```

The proble is that with this the buttons won't work correctly (I suppose the problem is that there isn't actually any `/it/` in the URL to switch with `/en/`). So I think I need a more "sophisticated" RewriteRule.

Can anyone help me?

Many thanks!

MIX

Answer (score 0):

You just need this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ /it/index.html [L]
```